# How can I move property in array by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

My array like this :

===============================================================

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "description": "Chelsea is the best team",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 101,
                    "name": "Sterling",
                    "country": "England",
                    "club_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 102,
                    "name": "Alonso",
                    "country": "Spain",
                    "club_id": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Real Madrid",
            "description": "Real Madrid is the spain team",
            "players": [
                {
                    "id": 103,
                    "name": "Courtois",
                    "country": "Belgia",
                    "club_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

===============================================================

I want to change the array to be like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "description": "Chelsea is the best team",
            "name": "Sterling",
            "country": "England",
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "description": "Chelsea is the best team",
            "name": "Alonso",
            "country": "Spain",
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "Real Madrid",
            "description": "Real Madrid is the spain team",
            "name": "Courtois",
            "country": "Belgia",
        }
    ]
}
```

===============================================================

So I move the football player according to the club id like that

Please help. Thanks

Comment: An object can't have duplicate keys - like `name` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this.

Since you can't have two keys with the same name (because that wouldn't make sense), the player's `name` is their name and `teamName` is their team's name.

```js
const data = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Chelsea","description":"Chelsea is the best team","players":[{"id":101,"name":"Sterling","country":"England","club_id":1},{"id":102,"name":"Alonso","country":"Spain","club_id":1}]},{"id":2,"name":"Real Madrid","description":"Real Madrid is the spain team","players":[{"id":103,"name":"Courtois","country":"Belgia","club_id":2}]}]}

const newData = {
  data: data.data.flatMap(
    (team) => team.players.map((player) => ({
      ...player,
      teamName: team.name,
      teamDescription: team.description,
    }))
  )
};

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: You don't omit `club_id` from the final object.